# Super product attributes same price for attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, configurable-product, superattribute

This is a bit hard to explain. But in Super product attributes configuration there is a field where you can set a cost that is added to the product. I want to be able to have this price sett as a standard every time this attribute is used.

In this case it is hotel booking, so 3 days is NOK 700,- extra and 4 nights is 1400,- extra.

Is it possible to make this extra cost come up on every configurable product automatically? I want to avoid having to enter inn this extra price every time I create a configurable product. The products are always the same, just with a different name.

Thanks so much for reading this, and hope you can help. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You best chance is to duplicate the same configurable product and change the name and other different attributes of the duplicated product.

I reckon you should have a good read at this post to help you implement the duplication of options: [Clone configurable product with related simple products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42305/clone-configurable-product-with-related-simple-products)